# How to resolve Trying to create too many scroll contexts. Must be less than or equal to: [500]?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I'm trying to query from Elastic DB. So for 90000 Records I need to hit elastic DB for two different occasions.My query is as follows.

```
    var queryobj = {

    "query": {

        "bool": {

            "must": [

                {

                    "match": {

                        "mobile": value

                    }
                }

            ],

        }
    }

};
var { _scroll_id, hits, took } = await elasticClient.search({
    index: 'mobiledata',     
    type: '_doc',
    scroll: '20m',
    filterPath: '_scroll_id,hits.hits._source,took',
    size: 10000,
    body: queryobj
});

if (hits) {
    console.log("hits ", hits);
    return hits.hits;
}
return hits;
```

While trying to exectue this, I'm getting error like :

```
 { Error: [exception] Trying to create too many scroll contexts. Must be less than or equal to: 
 [500]. This limit can be set by changing the [search.max_open_scroll_context] setting.
 status: 500,
 displayName: 'InternalServerError',
 message: '[exception] Trying to create too many scroll contexts. Must be less than or equal to: 
 [500]. This limit can be set by changing the [search.max_open_scroll_context] setting.',
```

Can anybody help me how to fix this error?

Comment: Why are you setting a 20m scroll timeout? pretty sure that 5m is more than sufficient. Also as it stands, you're probably not iterating through all the results. Finally, you should destroy the scroll context when you're done with the query.

Comment: I have updated as 5m. Could you please explain about destroying the scroll context ?

Comment: I'm talking about [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/clear-scroll-api.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
await elasticClient.clearScroll({scroll_id: _scroll_id});
```

Whenever you want to close the scroll api and open another scroll api, please run the above code.
It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions did not work for me, so I resolved it like this on Linux:

1. Go to this path:

   ```
   ".local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/opensearchpy/helpers"
   ```
2. Open `action.py` file.
3. Change wherever the chunk size is `500` into `10000` and save the file.

Comment: While I'm sure that the hack worked for you... it is an hack, not really a robust solution. Is there a way to have a better solution using your idea?